# Ensime can't find java?

Tags: java, windows, emacs, ensime

When I start ensime in Emacs, it immediately crashes saying:

```
'"java"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Process *inferior-ensime-server-documents* exited abnormally with code 1.
```

This is strange, because when I write `java` in cmd (in Windows 8), it runs. I added java both to Emacs's `exec-path` and the system's `Path` variables. Also I'm surprised it is in triple quotes, `'"java"'`. Do these quotes interfere? And what to do with them?

My .ensime file (created via `sbt gen-ensime`) looks like this:

```
(
     :root-dir "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala"
     :cache-dir "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\.ensime_cache"
     :name "skala"
     :java-home "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_07\\bin"
     :java-flags ("-Xmx512M" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m" "- Dsbt.log.format=true")
     :reference-source-roots nil
     :scala-version "2.10.4"
     :compiler-args nil

 :subprojects ((
   :name "skala"
   :module-name "skala"
   :source-roots ("C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\src\\main\\scala"     "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\src\\main\\java" "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\src\\test\\scala" "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\src\\test\\java")
       :target "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\target\\scala-2.10\\classes"
       :test-target "C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\Documents\\skala\\target\\scala-2.10\\test-classes"
       :depends-on-modules nil
       :compile-deps ("C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\.sbt\\boot\\scala-2.10.4\\lib\\scala-library.jar")
       :runtime-deps nil
      :test-deps nil
       :reference-source-roots ("C:\\Users\\leokr_000\\.ivy2\\cache\\org.scala-lang\\scala-library\\srcs\\scala-library-2.10.4-sources.jar")))

)
```

Comment: Good catch on the quotes -- it looks like the program Emacs is trying to run is `"java"`, with double quotes around it. What does your .ensime file look like, and how did you create it?

Comment: well, I generated it. I can't paste it here in comment, so I have pasted it above.

Comment: I notice that on the line that starts `:java-flags`, you have a string given as `"- Dsbt.log.format=true"`. Is there really a space after the `-`? There shouldn't be.

Comment: sorry, I put these spaces by accident when trying to format it to blockquote. So they aren't there really. Maybe I should also mention that I run polish version of Windows 8. Are there some environment settings regarding single and double quotes? Why triple quote?

Comment: The "triple quotes" are double quotes flanked by single quotes. I don't have Windows at hand, but I believe its command shell uses single quotes around command names in the context `'program' is not recognized as an internal or external command…`; so in this case the actual program it's attempting to run has double quotes around it, from the looks of it. I hope that makes sense. As for *why*, I can't see any reason. Hopefully someone else can help you out.

Comment: "java" works in my cmd but 'java' or `java` or whatever doesn't. OK, so thank you. Do you know how to run this "ensime" command in some debug mode to get full traceback and not just error? I won't fix it, but maybe someone will.

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps the `*inferior-ensime-server-PROJECT-NAME*` buffer would give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your `:java-home` is wrong, I don't know how you can run anything in `sbt` with this setup. Remove the `\\bin` from this and investigate why it is being incorrectly generated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could build with sbt. After some random changes, I even managed to use ensime, but I didn't like it more than ScalaIDE. Emacs is probably for real hackers.

Comment: SBT doesn't use the .ensime file. Your Java home is incorrect.